# Amazon SNS : How to send a push to multiple recipients without using Topics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Amazon SNS (Simple Notification Service) can break down my recipients to "Topics" which can then be used to send some messages to particular sub-segment of my app audience.
Let's say I have so many sub-segments of audiences that I can't use SNS Topics anymore (due to their limit). 
Sending one by one is a heavy task.

Is it somehow possible to upload a list of pushIDs to SNS and then set the message and send the push message?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can upload a list, bit you could ask AWS for limit increase or use multiple accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can request a topic limit increase here: https://aws.amazon.com/support/createCase

Unless you need some insane number of topics, this is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple micro ec2 instances to get over api limits. For this you have to divide workers into multiple instances. We implemented this a while ago and still using it without any problem.